# Yii2 save tag-post via Ajax on dropdown change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I am trying to save tag in database table every time Html::DropDownList option is changed. On debug session it redirects me on `ErrorHandler.php` but no error is shown.

my jQuery:

```
var ddList = $('.dd-list');
var tagList = $('.tag-container');

ddList.on('change', function () {
    var tagHolder = document.createElement('div');
    tagHolder.setAttribute('class', 'tag-holder');
    var selected = $('.dd-list option:selected').text();
    tagHolder.setAttribute('id', selected);

    if(tagList.find('div').length > 2){
        alert('You can have most 3 tags!');
        return false;
    };

    if(tagList.find('#'+selected).length){
        return false;
    }else{
        tagHolder.append(selected);
        tagList.append(tagHolder);

        $.ajax({
            method : 'GET',
            dataType : 'text',
            url : '../post/save-tag?tag=' + selected,
            success : function (data) {
                alert("Tag saved: " + data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

actionSaveTag :

```
public function actionSaveTag($tag)
    {
        return \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO tags(tag_name)
                                            VALUES (' . $tag . ')');
    }
```

I tried also `VALUES ($tag)` without single quotes but same result.
How should i make it? Appreciating all advices!

Comment: Check if you get anything in Debug ->Request, GET. Try $model = new Tag(); $model->name = what you received in GET, then attempt to save, and wrap that in a `if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)`. Why use Yii2 if you go almost vanilla and make no use of the framework?

Comment: Because i am still new and do not know which is the right way :) I just made it with adding `->execute()` in the end of the query. But will try to correct my code and use more of Yii2 functions :)

Comment: Sorry, man, didnt intend to be aggressive, was on my phone. Will come back with an explanation.

Comment: Don't worry :) I know my question are stupid sometimes but at least i have to start from somewhere :)